# R - read multiple tables from text files of different format

Tags: r, machine-learning, nlp

I have several text files converted from images using [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition). Some of the text files contains multiple tables. These files differ in number of columns, separator and the line on which data starts. Below are the sample 2 files:

***file1.txt*:** contains two tables in single text file

```
                                         Receipt
Date: 12/05/2015    Page: 1 
Status: Active
Location: Florida, USA

Prod ID Category ID Product Name Received Date Quantity       Price
1       201         ABC          02/01/2015    5              200   
2                                02/01/2015    1              100   
3       204         XYZ          05/02/2015    10              2000   

                                      Total    16             2300


Date: 01/02/2016    Page: 2 
Status: Complete
Location: Florida, USA

Prod ID Category ID Product Name Received Date Quantity       Price
1       202         ABC          02/01/2015    5              200   
2       203         MNO          02/01/2015    1              100   
3       204         XYZ          05/02/2015    10              2000   

                                     Total    16             2300
```

***file2.txt*:** contains one table but in different format than above

```
Receipt Date: 12/05/2015    Page: 1   Location: California, USA     Status: Complete

Prod ID  Product  Received     Sent      Quantity   Price
           Name     Date       Date        
1         ABC     02/01/2015  03/01/2015   5          200   
2         PQR     02/01/2015  03/01/2015   1          100   
3         XYZ     05/02/2015  03/02/2015   10         2000
```

I am looking to read the files and create dataframe for each file/table. Is there any way to apply machine learning/[NLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuro-linguistic_programming) to convert these text files into dataframe in R.

Comment: DO the tables you want always start with a line that starts with "Prod ID"?

Comment: Not always. It can be other column or a new column also